# mysql ignore filed using SET

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Doing so I got zero affected row.

```
const fields = ['name','age', 'createdAt'].filter(field => field !== 'createdAt').map(field => `${field} = ?`).join(', ');

const query = `UPDATE configurations SET ${fields}  WHERE id = ? `;
```

The problem is at `filter(field => field !== 'createdAt')`, but if I remove this my createdAt will be null. How to I ignore (keep the previous value) of createdAt?

Comment: What is your desired raw MySQL query?  I don't think your current code is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Your code looks fine. If you don't update the value of `createdAt` in the query then it will keep its old value.